Conditional von neumann entropy
Can someone show me how to proof this relation:
If $\rho_{ABC}$ is a pure state, then $S(A|C)=-S(A|B)$
I already know that $S(A|B)=S(\rho_{AB})-S(\rho_{B})$ and that I should somehow use that $S(\rho_{A})=S(\rho_{B})$ if $\rho_{AB}$ is a pure state.
